# Color dataframe based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas, colors

I would like to color the dataframe based on the condition below

```py
   LL    UL   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4 
1   0    10     5       -6      13      46
2   3    12     0        5       8      55
3 NaN   NaN    -9        8       4       5
```

I want to color `col_1` `col_2` `col_3` and `col_4` if the values is lower than column `LL` or higher than `UL` in each row.

If lower, color it red. If higher, color it green.

Moreover, if there is no upper limit and no lower limit, do nothing in that row.

Thanks!

The results may look like this
[image]

Comment: What you have tried in code to achieve the same?

Comment: I have used `df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)` , but I have no idea how to write the condition code in highlight function.

Comment: Dupe was wrong so reopened, solution is more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare all columns by `LL` and `UL` columns and return style DataFrame filled by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: green'
    c3 = '' 
    m1 = x.lt(x['LL'], axis=0)
    m2 = x.gt(x['UL'], axis=0)
    #if necessary set first 2 columns to False
    m1.iloc[:, :2] = False
    m2.iloc[:, :2] = False

    out = np.select([m1, m2], [c1, c2], default=c3)
    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

---

```
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: pic]