# Pandas Styles removing default table format

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, pandas-styles

I am trying to format a pandas DataFrame value representation.
Basically, all I want is to get the "Thousand" separator on my values.

I managed to do it using the **pd.style.format** function. It does the job, but also "breaks" all my table original design.

here is an example of what is going on:
[image: Example]

Is there anything I can do to avoid doing it? I want to keep the original table format, only changing the format of the value.

PS: Don't know if it makes any difference, but I am using Google Colab.

Comment: This does not seem to be the behaviour in pandas 1.3.2 what version are you using?

Comment: It was indeed an older version. Just updated but stills the same result

Comment: Interesting, you are correct colab doesn't seem to handle this as nicely as jupyter notebook does.

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue: [Pandas style doesn't work with Google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62255818/15497888)

Comment: Not sure if it is good or bad news... But  I guess I will have to go back JupyterNotebook for this project then.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is having the same problem as I was using Colab, I have found a solution:

**.set_table_attributes('class="dataframe"')** seems to solve the problem

More infos can be found here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1687

Answer (score 0):

For this case you could do:

```
pdf.assign(a=pdf['a'].map("{:,.0f}".format))
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this using a dictionary? My example is only changing the format of a single column, but in real life I got a few more